# Python list of substrings in list of strings

Tags: python, list, substring

I'd like to find if a list of substrings is contained in a list. For example, I have:

```
    string_list = ['item1', 'item2', 'subject3', 'subject4']
```

and list of substrings

```
    substrings = ['item', 'subject']
```

I'd like to find if 'item' or 'subject' are included in any item of string_list. Individually, I would do something like:

```
    any('item' in x for x in string_list)
```

This works for one substring but I would like to find a pretty way of searching for both strings in the list of substrings.

Comment: You could nest `any`s, or write a more complex generator expression to create the cross product, or use `itertools.product` to do it for you.

Comment: What is your expected result?  Do you want matches where the `string_list` starts with the `substring` item, or exact matches?

Comment: I'd just like a true or false of whether or not the list of strings contains any of the the strings in the substring list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
any(y in x for x in string_list for y in substrings)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the substrings are actually at the start, you can use [`str.startswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) which can take a tuple of prefixes:

```
any(x.startswith(('item', 'subject')) for x in string_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
string_list = ['item1', 'item2', 'subject3', 'subject4']

substrings = ['item', 'subject']

any(any(b in i for b in substrings) for i in string_list)
```

Output:

```
True
```